# How can I combine the CheckingFuelMonad with a State monad in Hoopl?

Tags: haskell, monads, state-monad, hoopl

I am using the [Hoopl](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hoopl) library and would like to carry some state around while rewriting. The rewrite functions are polymorphic regarding the monad used, but I cannot figure out how to combine a `State` monad with one of the library's `Fuel` monads.

Below is a minimal example. `MyMonad` is a synonym combining Hoopl's `CheckingFuelMonad` and a `State` monad carrying a flag. `Stmt` is just a placeholder for my intermediate language and isn't really important.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, RankNTypes #-}

import Compiler.Hoopl
import Control.Monad.State

type MyMonad = CheckingFuelMonad (State Bool)

data Stmt e x where
  Bind :: () -> Stmt O O

rewriter :: forall e x. Stmt e x -> Fact x () -> MyMonad (Maybe (Graph Stmt e x))
rewriter (Bind ()) () = return $ do
  f <- get
  if f 
   then return $ Just emptyGraph
   else return Nothing
```

But this will not compile -- GHC complains that `rewrite` has the wrong type:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Graph' Block Stmt e x'
       against inferred type `Maybe (g n O O)'
  Expected type: CheckingFuelMonad
                   (State Bool) (Maybe (Graph Stmt e x))
  Inferred type: CheckingFuelMonad
                   (State Bool) (Maybe (Maybe (g n O O)))
```

Is what I want to do possible? How can I write the `rewrite` function correctly?

Comment: I am super unconvinced that this rewrite is sound. This is very dodgy business.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A browse through hoopl code reveals that CheckingFuelMonad isn't an instance of MonadTrans, and you can't make it one, since its constructors are not exported. You *can* however wrap a StateT around CheckingFuelMonad, like so:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, RankNTypes #-}

import Compiler.Hoopl
import Control.Monad.State

type MyMonad = StateT Bool SimpleFuelMonad

data Stmt e x where
  Bind :: () -> Stmt O O

rewriter :: forall e x. Stmt e x -> Fact x () -> MyMonad (Maybe (Graph Stmt e x))
rewriter (Bind ()) () = do
  f <- get
  if f
   then return $ Just emptyGraph
   else return Nothing
```

Comment: The funny part is, if you look at the implementation of `CheckingFuelMonad`, it's just `StateT Fuel` itself.

Comment: That helps me get a little farther! Unfortunately `MyMonad` must be an instance of `FuelMonad`, and I don't think I can make it one since the class members are not exported. However, I am able to get away with `mkBRewrite (\s f -> evalStateT (rewriter s f) False)`. Unfortunately I think that means the state will not be preserved across individual statements - we'll see!

Comment: @Justin Bailey: Everything from `FuelMonad` looks like it's exported to me. Also, I'm pretty sure that order is irrelevant for *adjacent* `StateT` layers, so `sclv`'s version should be equivalent to putting `State` inside the `SimpleFuelMonad`.

Comment: Ah, nevermind, I see now--only the `FuelMonad` class is re-exported from `Compiler.Hoopl`. Oh well. I assume the reason for this is to keep client code from mucking with the fuel remaining in invalid ways, but I don't see why `lift getFuel` and `lift setFuel` would be problematic. Could hack the library to let you do it, I guess. Meh.

Comment: I think you're right... it looks like there's a whole bunch of implementation-hiding in place to the extent where certain things become quite difficult. I imagine you'll have to do a fair amount of threading around by hand...

Comment: @sclv: Well, I gather the whole point of Hoopl is to restrict what you can do so that only things that can be optimized effectively can be written, so it makes sense. I think that what @Justin Bailey is trying to do is completely safe, just not accounted for in the library, but... not 100% certain, because I'm not very familiar with Hoopl's internals.

Comment: The inability to carry around your own state is one of the drawback's of their design, I think. I've had to work around it in numerous ways, usually by optimizing is two passes.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the immediate cause of your current error is simple. What is the final expression if `f` is true? If we take this:

```
rewriter :: forall e x. Stmt e x -> Fact x () -> MyMonad (Maybe (Graph Stmt e x))
rewriter (Bind ()) () = return $ do
  f <- get
  if f 
   then return $ Just emptyGraph
   else return Nothing
```

...and remove everything but the `True` branch we get:

```
rewriter :: forall e x. Stmt e x -> Fact x () -> MyMonad (Maybe (Graph Stmt e x))
rewriter (Bind ()) () = return $ do
  return $ Just emptyGraph
```

...which simplifies to:

```
rewriter :: forall e x. Stmt e x -> Fact x () -> MyMonad (Maybe (Graph Stmt e x))
rewriter (Bind ()) () = return $ return $ Just emptyGraph
```

What's the type of `return $ return $ Just emptyGraph`?

```
(Monad m1, Monad m2, GraphRep g) => m1 (m2 (Maybe (g n O O)))
```

In other words, you've got an extra `return` in there. `(Monad m) => CheckingFuelMonad m` is itself a `Monad`, even though `CheckingFuelMonad` doesn't seem to be defined as a monad transformer, so you've only got one monad layer to `return` with.

Comment: @Justin Bailey: Hence why I said "immediate cause". Removing the `return` outside the `do` block just reduces it to the actual problem, which is what `sclv` talks about.